# Parsing a syslog using Regex

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

I am writing a Regex to parse a syslog entry. I am having challenges to able parse the entry until i hit "CMD". I would like all that appears after CMD to be grouped under (). Also, can you please provide suggestions to improve the regex

Here is my syslog entry:

> Nov 21 23:17:01 ubuntu-xenial CRON[10299]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)

```
(<?month>[A-z]{3})\s(<?date>[0-9]{2}?)\s(<?time>[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)\s(<?hostname>[a-z]+-[a-z]+)\s(<?daemon>[A-Z]+)(<?pid>\[[0-9]+\]):\s(<?user>\([a-z]+\))
```

Comment: Your regex syntax is completely wrong. This can't work. Your named capture groups are wrong. It should be `(<?name>[a-z]+)`, not `[(<?name>)[a-z]+`

Comment: "[ ]" were added as i copied from an online parser. but the intent was (<?cpature-group>[a-z]+)

Comment: What happens when the day of the month has only a single digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my revisions, with comments. In general, you might be better off making fewer assumptions about what the fields are going to contain. Here I'm using `\S` which is "anything except whitespace". Furthermore, `\s+` will match some whitespace, whether that's just one character or more.

```
(<?month>\S+)                    #
\s+                              # added + because single digit dates might have additional spaces
(<?date>[0-9]{1,2})              # changed {2}? to {1,2} because you might have one or two digits
\s+                              #
(<?time>[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)    #   
\s+                              #
(<?hostname>\S+)                 # anything which isn't whitespace
\s+                              #
(<?daemon>\S+)                   # just in case your daemon has a digit or lower case in its name
(<?pid>\[[0-9]+\])               #
:                                #
\s+                              #
\((<?user>\S+)\)                 # your username might have digits in it; don't capture the brackets
\s+                              #
CMD                              #
\s+                              #
\((<?command>.*)\)               # capture the command, not the brackets
\s*                              # in case of trailing space
$                                # match end of string
```